# Фильтрация строк DataFrame/Series по фрагменту строкового значения

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется Series-объект `df.col_1` - конкретный столбец датафрейма `df`, содержащий строковые значения, типа:

```
1       В процессе исключения из ЕГРЮЛ c 20 февраля 20...
2       Контрагента могут ликвидировать. Внесена запис...
3       Контрагента могут ликвидировать. Внесена запис...
4       Контрагента могут ликвидировать. Внесена запис...
5       Контрагента могут ликвидировать. Внесена запис...
6       ФНС приняла решение о предстоящем исключении к...
7       В процессе исключения из ЕГРЮЛ c 27 февраля 20...
8       Контрагента могут ликвидировать. Внесена запис...
9       Контрагента могут ликвидировать. Внесена запис...
10      ФНС приняла решение о предстоящем исключении к...
11      Контрагента могут ликвидировать. Внесена запис...
12      Контрагента могут ликвидировать. Внесена запис...
13      ФНС приняла решение о предстоящем исключении к...
14      ФНС приняла решение о предстоящем исключении к...
15      ФНС приняла решение о предстоящем исключении к...
```

Необходимо отфильтровать такие наблюдения, которые содержать фрагмент, например "ФНС" в составе строки.

Код

```
df.col_1.filter(like='ФНС')
```

или

```
df.col_1.filter(regex='ФНС')
```

не дает нужного результата.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [Series.str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
In [78]: df[df['col_1'].str.contains('ФНС')]
Out[78]:
                                                col_1
5   ФНС приняла решение о предстоящем исключении к...
9   ФНС приняла решение о предстоящем исключении к...
12  ФНС приняла решение о предстоящем исключении к...
13  ФНС приняла решение о предстоящем исключении к...
14  ФНС приняла решение о предстоящем исключении к...
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно